# What creature am I? (Strange hybrid creature)

Tags: riddle

> The antlers of a deer.
>   The head of a crocodile.
>  
>   The neck of a snake.
>   A cow's ears.
>   A hawk's claws.
>   The palms of a tiger.
>   A carp's scales.

What creature am I?

Comment: This seems to be more like trivia than a riddle. There's no wordplay, metaphor, or misdirection involved. It's just a basic description of an object; if you happen to know that object exists, it's easy; if you don't, you'll try to find non-obvious interpretations of the words and won't get anywhere.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Are you

> Chinese Dragon

If we merge them together, it will form

> [image]

Comment: nice image HAHAHHA

Comment: Man, this cracked me up. Awesomeness achieved!

Comment: If you hovered the large spoiler area, well... good luck sleeping tonight.

Comment: I can't help myself but laughing out loud

Comment: @ShaneHsu Well then, it means marius is wrong .

Comment: He, he, that depends. My families figured the riddle out after I read the first two line, and they burst into laughter as soon as they saw the photoshoped image.

Comment: @ShaneHsu Well, this is called illustration with an comic aspect.